# guardでテストが自動で動かない

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

guardでテストの自動化を行おうとしているのですが、立ち上げることはできても、ファイルを変更しても自動でテストが起動してくれずこまっています。下記が起動時のメッセージです。

```
[vagrant@localhost sample_app]$ bundle exec guard
which: no notify-send in (/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bin:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/.rbenv/libexec:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin:/usr/local/.rbenv/bin:/home/vagrant/bin)
09:57:29 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
09:57:29 - INFO - Starting Spork for RSpec
Using RSpec, Rails
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
09:57:32 - INFO - Spork server for RSpec successfully started

09:57:32 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
09:57:32 - INFO - Running all specs
Running tests with args ["--color", "--failure-exit-code", "2", "--format", "progress", "--format", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter", "--require", "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/guard-rspec-2.5.0/lib/guard/rspec/formatter.rb", "spec"]...
.......F.

Failures:

1) Static pages Home page should have the right title
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title("#{base_title} | Home")
   expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home") to return true, got false
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.33095 seconds
9 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:11 # Static pages Home page should have the right title


Randomized with seed 13620

Done.

09:57:34 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/vagrant/sample_app'
[1] guard(main)>
```

ここまでは動くのですが、その後ファイルを変更しても自動でテストが走ってくれません。

Guardfileが下記になります。

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme
require 'active_support/inflector'
guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch('config/environments/test.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { :test_unit }
  watch(%r{features/support/}) { :cucumber }
end

guard 'rspec', all_after_pass: false do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }

  # Custom Rails Tutorial specs
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  do |m|
    ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
     "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb",
     "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
     (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" :
         "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")]
  end
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/}) do |m|
    (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" :
        "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")
  end
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/sessions_controller\.rb$}) do |m|
    "spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb"
  end
end
```

環境は下記です。
centos 6.6
Rails 4.0.5
ruby 2.2.1

gem 'guard', '2.6.1'
gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ぱっと見、おかしなところはなさそうな気がしますね。
変更したファイルは具体的にどのファイルですか？
`./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`を適当に変更して保存しても反応はありませんか？

あと、Guardにはdebugモードがあります。
これを付けて動かしたときの実行結果も追記してもらうと何かヒントが見つかるかもしれません。

`bundle exec guard -d`

参考までに、こちらにGuardを使ったサンプルアプリケーションがあります。
（「[Everyday Rails - RSpecによるRailsテスト入門](https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec-jp)」という電子書籍のサンプルアプリケーションです）

- https://github.com/everydayrails/rspec_rails_4 (RSpec 2系)
- https://github.com/everydayrails/rails-4-1-rspec-3-0 (RSpec 3系)

これをローカルに落としてGuardが動くかどうか確認してみるのも一つの手です。
僕のローカルではファイルの変更に反応してテストが再実行されました。
（Firefoxが途中で止まる場合はselenium-webdriverのバージョンを上げてください）

#### 追記

Vagrantを使っているようなので、この件が近いかもしれません。

http://dev.akinaka.net/2014/01/16/vagrant-nfs-guard

> nfsマウント時はホスト側のファイル変更イベントを、ゲスト側が受け取れないという事がわかりました。
>
> (中略)
>
> guardは本来ファイルの変更を検知してテストの処理等が走るのですが、
>   ポーリングさせてファイルの変更を監視させる事もできるようです。
>
> ずばり下記の通り。
>
> $ bundle exec guard -p

その他、「Vagrant Guard」というキーワードで検索するといろいろと情報がヒットするので、この中に解答が見つかるかもしれません。
（僕は普段VagrantやGuardを使わないので細かい事情はちょっとわかりませんが）

#### 追記2

昨日公開されたこちらの記事でもポーリングの話が載ってますね。

http://qiita.com/masuidrive/items/0e0e5294bc2dc81a52c2

> Vagrant上での開発の注意点
>
> Guardで自動テストが走らないときは、guard -pとポーリングオプションを付ける

Comment: @yusuke-higaki さん、いくつか解決策の候補を挙げましたが、結局どれが有効だったのか教えてください。そうすれば同じ問題に遭遇している他の人にとっても参考になると思うので。