# guard + minitest を自動で動かせない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

環境：
`CentOS6.7`, `ruby 2.2.2p95`, `rails 4.2.4`
CentOSは`vagrant`経由で起動した、`virtualbox`上の仮想ゲストOSです。

今まで使ったことのなかった`guard`の実験をしています。

```
--Guardfile--
guard :minitest do
  watch '/opt/rails/rails_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.haml'
end
```

ファイルの指定は間違ってないように思います。

```
$ ls /opt/rails/rails_app/app/views/static_pages/
about.html.haml  help.html.haml  home.html.haml
```

中身はこれだけです。

```
$ cat /opt/rails/rails_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.haml 
= provide :title, 'home'
%h1 StaticPages#home
```

テストは次のように用意しました。

```
$ cat test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb 
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    @base_title = 'ROR tutorial'
  end

  test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
    assert_select 'title', "home | #{@base_title}"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get :help
    assert_response :success
    assert_select 'title', "help | #{@base_title}"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get :about
    assert_response :success
    assert_select 'title', "about | #{@base_title}"
  end
end
```

`Gemfile`での`guard`に関する部分は次のとおりです。

```
$ cat Gemfile | grep guard
gem 'guard', group: :development
gem 'guard-minitest', group: :development
```

この後`guard`を起動し、それ自体の起動は問題なさそうに見えました。

```
$ bundle exec guard -p
13:31:34 - INFO - Guard::Minitest 2.4.4 is running, with Minitest::Unit 5.8.2!
13:31:34 - INFO - Running: all tests
Run options: --seed 5814
# Running:
...
Finished in 1.391047s, 2.1566 runs/s, 4.3133 assertions/s.
3 runs, 6 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
13:32:00 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/opt/rails/rails_app'
[1] guard(main)>
```

が、これ以降、`app/views/static_pages/home.html.haml`を編集・保存しても全く`guard`の挙動に動いた形跡が見られません。例えばわざとエラーが起きるような修正をしても何の反応もなく、手動で`rake test`するときちんとエラーが返ってくるという状況です。

[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7609/guard%E3%81%A7%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%8C%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E3%81%A7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)を見て、`guard -p` も試してみましたが、結果が変わりません。
そもそも共有フォルダもnfsも関係のない場所で処理しているので、最初から無関係だったようです。

`Guardfile`の中身を少しでも書き換えると`guard`が自動再起動してテストの読み込み・実行を行うことは確認できたので、十中八九、`Guardfile`の書き間違いなのだろうとは思うのですが、正規表現ではなくファイルを直接指定する書き方をしているつもりなので、これで動かないとなるとどういうことなのか混乱しています。
何かしらヒントをご存じの方がいらしたら、ご教示をお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guardfileを以下のように変更してみて下さい。
`app/views/static_pages/home.html.haml`が変更されると、`test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb`が実行されるようになるはずです。

```
guard :minitest, test_folders: 'test', all_on_start: false, spring: true do
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$}) \
    { |m| "test/controllers/#{m[1]}_controller_test.rb" }
end
```

ちなみに上のコードは拙著「[RSpecユーザのためのMinitestチュートリアル](https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec-jp)」で解説したGuardfileがベースになっています。
これ以外のパターンも載っているので、良かったら参考にしてみて下さい。

### 追記

> 直接ファイルを指定する方法（watch('Gemfile.lock')のような書き方があった）から試してみたのに駄目だったのは何が理由だった‌​か、ヒントでいいので教えていただくことはできますでしょうか。

https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Guardfile-examples ではminitestの場合のサンプルが載ってないですね。
直接ファイルだけを指定するパターンだと、`guard :bundler`や`guard :pow`にしか載ってません。
比較的形式が近いのは`guard 'rspec'`ですが、形式が近いだけであって、全く同じではありません。

参考にするのであれば、 https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest を見るのが良いと思います。

guard-minitestの場合、

`watch(監視するファイルの正規表現) {|m| 変更があったときに実行するテストファイル }`

の形式でGuardfileを定義します。
（`#{m[1]}`のような部分には正規表現でマッチした文字列が入ります）

正規表現を使わずに

`watch(特定のファイルパス) {|m| 変更があったときに実行するテストファイル }`

のように書くこともできますが、

`watch(特定のファイルパス)`

だけだと、「そのファイルが変更されても、どのテストを実行したらいいかわからないので、結局何も起きない」という結果になってしまいます。

Comment: 動きました。ありがとうございます。それはそうと、https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Guardfile-examples　こちらのサンプルを見て、直接ファイルを指定する方法（watch('Gemfile.lock')のような書き方があった）から試してみたのに駄目だったのは何が理由だったか、ヒントでいいので教えていただくことはできますでしょうか。一番疑いようのないやり方で最初に試すには良いと思ったのですが……